# Mobile App Authentication

Tags: authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have created a mobile app that uses my web api (so I own both the app and the api). To do this, I have used oauth2 user credentials grant - as per: https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/user-credentials/

This allows a user to login to the app using there normal website credentials (username / password). The app then receives a bearer token from the website, this bearer token is used to interact with the web api.

My question is, how do I limit my web api so that ONLY my app can use it? At this moment, others could develop other apps that use my api as the app itself isnt authorized (its just using the username/password of the website users).

Do apps get given a unique id by the play store / iOS when published? that I can use to authenticate the app making the api requests?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
Ollie

Comment: Sorry Neil - The difficulty is finding the same context. Searching for mobile authentication comes up with 000's of results - all different to what I'm after (eg - I dont care about facebook / twitter authentication etc). Either i'm terrible at searching, or the Search needs improving to help filter results. Do you have a particular thread I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because anything on the client side is intrinsically compromised, we must look deeper into what determines the authenticity of a client. The most obvious, of course, would be the client secret. However, since this is a client-side app, that's a non-starter because anyone with reasonable know-how could inspect the source to find it.

However, what many people overlook is that a client also has a specific, unique redirect URI that is determined when it is configured. Thus, if you register your redirect URI with the platform (iOS, Android, etc.), then only your client will be capable of successfully completing the flow.

Unfortunately, that's not enough to prevent truly dedicated attackers. If an attacker manages to get an app installed on the client's device and registers the redirect URI, it could intercept the authorization tokens and partake in the flow:

```
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
| End Device (e.g., Smartphone)  |
|                                |
| +-------------+   +----------+ | (6) Access Token  +----------+
| |Legitimate   |   | Malicious|<--------------------|          |
| |OAuth 2.0 App|   | App      |-------------------->|          |
| +-------------+   +----------+ | (5) Authorization |          |
|        |    ^          ^       |        Grant      |          |
|        |     \         |       |                   |          |
|        |      \   (4)  |       |                   |          |
|    (1) |       \  Authz|       |                   |          |
|   Authz|        \ Code |       |                   |  Authz   |
| Request|         \     |       |                   |  Server  |
|        |          \    |       |                   |          |
|        |           \   |       |                   |          |
|        v            \  |       |                   |          |
| +----------------------------+ |                   |          |
| |                            | | (3) Authz Code    |          |
| |     Operating System/      |<--------------------|          |
| |         Browser            |-------------------->|          |
| |                            | | (2) Authz Request |          |
| +----------------------------+ |                   +----------+
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
```

Thus, RFC 7636 sets forth the [Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) (PKCE, or "pixy") extension to the OAuth2 framework. Essentially, PKCE works by letting the client tell the authorization server know how to associate the code with a particular set of materials, like proof of possession but reduced in scope.

The client sends an additional two parameters when requesting an authorization code: a code challenge, and a code challenge method. The code challenge is formed from a cryptographically random string called the code verifier. The code verifier, along with the code challenge method, is used to bind the issued authorization code to the authorization request.

```
                                             +-------------------+
                                             |   Authz Server    |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ---->|               | |
   |        |       + t(code_verifier), t_m  | | Authorization | |
   |        |                                | |    Endpoint   | |
   |        |<-(B)---- Authorization Code -----|               | |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   | Client |                                |                   |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(C)-- Access Token Request ---->|               | |
   |        |          + code_verifier       | |    Token      | |
   |        |                                | |   Endpoint    | |
   |        |<-(D)------ Access Token ---------|               | |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
                                             +-------------------+
```

Most OAuth2 providers implement the PKCE flow, and there are plenty of online resources that go into more detail. Start with the RFC, and if you need clarification check out some other resources:

- http://lutando.net/2016/12/how-does-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce-by-oauth-work/